# a bound of the difference of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Somebody know a bound (upper or lower) of $(a-b)^{n}$ for  $n \in \textbf{N}$ ,$a \in \textbf{R}$ ,$b\in \textbf{R}$ ?

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean a bound *expressed in terms of $a$, $b$ and $n$?*

Comment: it would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but one upper bound is
$$
(a - b)^n \le e^{n(|a-b|-1)}
$$
since $\ln|a-b| \le |a - b| - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ even, the infimum is zero and the supremum is $+\infty$.
For $n$ odd, the supremum is again $+\infty$, while the infimum is $-\infty$.

In both cases, just choose $b=0$ and minimize/maximize with respect to $a$.

Answer (score 1):

$a^n$ is unbounded, so $(a-b)^n$ must also be unbounded; simply consider $b=0$ without loss of generality.